# Add "#" character to links from Layered Navigation Block

Tags: regex, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

### The problem

I have the following URL's in google webmaster tools:

`http://www.mydomain.com/product-category/attribute_name-value-attribute_name-value`

I need to write a rule in .htaccess that puts the `#` in my URLs, because the blocklayered module only filters with `#` in the link, like this:

`http://www.mydomain.com/product-category#/attribute_name-value-attribute_name-value`

### The reason

I need this because in webmaster tools there are lots of *error 404's* from links without `#`.

### Notes

I have friendly URL's activated in my prestashop backoffice.

Prestashop version 1.5.6.1 .

Server: shared hosting with apache.

### PS:

Basicly I need to write a rule to redirect all my links without `#` to the same links with `#` after the category.

*Thanks!*

Answer (score 1):

Redirect them from the url with `#` to the url without `#`

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\/(.*)$ $1#/$2 [R=301, L]
```

Or if you want to allow only specific characters

```
RewriteRule ^([\w\-]+)\/(.*)$ $1#/$2 [R=301, L]
```

Its not tested, but it should give you the idea.

Comment: I need the links without `#` redirected to the links with `#`.

Answer (score 0):

### My Solution

Hi,
First thanks for your answers, it helped pointed me in the right direction to resolve the issue.
For anyone who has the same problem:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^([\w\-]+)\/([\w\-]+)\-([\w]+)$ "http\:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\/$1\#\/$2\-$3 [R=301,L,NE]
```